AWS Glue Pyspark script for reading data from S3 and writing to S3 is taking hours to complete
`I am using pyspark on AWS Glue to run an ETL script as below:
```
`select
    date as date,
    hour as hour,
    trip_id as trip_id,
    first(user_id) as user_id,
    first(vehicle_id) as vehicle_id,
    count(ct) as total_driving_time,
    max(ct_list) as ct_list,
    max(sp_list) as sp_list,
    max(lt_list) as lt_list,
    max(ln_list) as ln_list
from (
        select date, hour, user_id, vehicle_id, trip_id, ct,
            collect_list(ct) OVER (PARTITION BY date, hour, trip_id ORDER BY ct) as ct_list,
            collect_list(sp) OVER (PARTITION BY date, hour, trip_id ORDER BY ct) as sp_list,
            collect_list(latitude) OVER (PARTITION BY date, hour, trip_id ORDER BY ct) as lt_list,
            collect_list(longitude) OVER (PARTITION BY date, hour, trip_id ORDER BY ct) as ln_list
        from table_temp
    ) t
group by date, hour, trip_id;`
```

data is partitioned on source and target but single partition data volume is quite a lot
the source S3 has 26 GB of data having 711396000
whereas the target resultant to be written to s3 is 3 rows only
below are the spark configurations I am using:
conf.set("spark.hadoop.parquet.read.allocation.size", "134217728")
conf.set("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", "536870912")
conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "536870912")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer", "bytebuffer")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.<region-name>.amazonaws.com")
conf.set("spark.sql.execution.pythonUDF.arrow.enabled", "True")

    df.coalesce(1).write.option("parquet.block.size",512*1024*1024).format("parquet").mode(write_mode).save(f"s3a://{buket_name}/{table_name}")`


Window operations are expensive; This transformation can be achieved with GROUP BY

SELECT
    date,
    hour,
    trip_id,
    FIRST(user_id) AS user_id,
    FIRST(vehicle_id) AS vehicle_id,
    COUNT(ct) AS total_driving_time,
    COLLECT_LIST(ct) AS ct_list,
    COLLECT_LIST(sp) AS sp_list,
    COLLECT_LIST(latitude) AS lt_list,
    COLLECT_LIST(longitude) AS ln_list
FROM table_temp
GROUP BY date, hour, trip_id



